# error checking with using while in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while True:
    self.soil_type = input("Please choose soil type - alkaline, neutral, acidic: ")
    print('-'*30)
    print('')
    if self.soil_type != "alkaline" and "neutral" and "acidic":
        print("***NOT A VALID SOIL TYPE***")
        continue
    else:
        False
```

I would like to make error checking with while loop.
If I type other than alkaline, neutral, acidic, print "not a valid soil type" and continue to the input command. If I type one of the right soil types, escape from the loop and go to the next step.

But it didn't work. Even if I typed right one (for example "acidic"), it showed "not a valid soil type". What am I missing? :)

Comment: Change your condition to this `if self.soil_type != "alkaline" and self.soil_type != "neutral" and self.soil_type != "acidic" `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while True:
    self.soil_type = input("Please choose soil type - alkaline, neutral, acidic: ")
    print('-'*30)
    print('')
    if not(self.soil_type == "alkaline" or self.soil_type == "neutral" or self.soil_type == "acidic"):
        print("***NOT A VALID SOIL TYPE***")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Try using this.....it should work!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the if condition wrong.

It should be something like -

```
while True:
    self.soil_type = input("Please choose soil type - alkaline, neutral, acidic: ")
    print('-'*30)
    print('')
    if (self.soil_type != "alkaline") and (self.soil_type != "neutral") and (self.soil_type != "acidic"):
        print("***NOT A VALID SOIL TYPE***")
        continue
    else:
        False
```

The reason is because you have put it like -

```
if <condition> and "neutral" and "acidic":
     ...
```

Since "neutral" and "acidic" are just true values, and the first condition will be true if it is not alkaline. This makes the whole condition true and it just prints -

```
***NOT A VALID SOIL TYPE***
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking `if not something`, your code will be more readable if you check `if something`:

```
while True:
    self.soil_type = input("Please choose soil type - alkaline, neutral, acidic: ")
    print('-'*30)
    print('')
    if self.soil_type == "alkaline" or self.soil_type == "neutral" or self.soil_type == "acidic":
      print("**VALID**")
      print self.soil_type
      break
    else:
      print("***NOT A VALID SOIL TYPE***")
```

**Reminder (Boolean algebra):**

> The rules can be expressed in English as:
>
> - the negation of a disjunction is the conjunction of the negations; and
> - the negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations; or
> - the complement of the union of two sets is the same as the intersection of their complements; and
> - the complement of the intersection of two sets is the same as the union of their complements.
>
> or
>
> ```
> not (A or B) = not A and not B; 
> and
> not (A and B) = not A or not B
> ```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, the "if" statement is syntactically incorrect. In addition, listing the set of valid soils in the if statement itself makes the code less readable and less easy to understand and maintain. Here's a suggestion that fixes this:

```
while True:
    valid_types = ('alkaline','neutral','acidic')
    self.soil_type = input("Please choose soil type - alkaline, neutral, acidic: ")
    print('-'*30)
    print('')
    if self.soil_type not in valid_types:
        print("***NOT A VALID SOIL TYPE***")
        continue
    else:
        False
```

While I suppose it's unlikely that the list of valid soil types will change, given the values you're giving us here, this still makes it clearer where the values come from.

Also, in the name of clarity, you can switch the if statements around, so that instead of checking if the input is *not* in the list, you can check that it *is*. That comes more naturally to most humans, again making the code more readable and maintainable:

```
while True:
    valid_types = ('alkaline','neutral','acidic')
    self.soil_type = input("Please choose soil type - alkaline, neutral, acidic: ")
    print('-'*30)
    print('')
    if self.soil_type in valid_types:
        False
    else:
        print("***NOT A VALID SOIL TYPE***")
        continue
```

For extra credit, edit the `input` with a little `join` etc to use the `valid_types` variable there too.